# isolate the action of a button from the action of it's div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

i have a div in my project and on this div a button that has an action of sliding the div down but the div itself has an action onclick to slide itself up

the problem here is that when i click the button the action of the button is done that the div slide down but also the action of the div is fired and slide up again coz the button is a part of it

i hope that i give you the point 
here is some code

```
<div id='container' onclick='slideup()'>
    <button onclick='slidedown()'>click</button>
</div>
```

which slideup and slidedown are functions added by my in javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `return false` to `function slidedown`

```
<div id='container' onclick='slideup()'>
    <button onclick='slidedown()'>click</button>
</div>

function slidedown(){
    ...
    ...
    return false;
}
```

---

since you tagged your question `jQuery`, why don't you use this wonderful library?

```
$('#container button').click(function(){ // or use $('#button-id')...
    slidedown();
    return false;
});

$('#container button').click(slideup);
```

**Updated HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
    <button >click</button> <!-- better give that button an id-->
</div>
```

Comment: or, using jQuery, `stopPropagation()`